# Terraform aws error creating IAM Role ecs_task_execution_role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I using terraform to deploy containers with fargate.

I got an error:

> ```
> error: Error creating IAM Role ecs_task_execution_role: MalformedPolicyDocument: Has prohibited field Resource
>         status code: 400, request id: 351d657b-32ef-4ffa-a1e8-bee912e5c788
>
>   on ecs.tf line 74, in resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_execution_role":
>   74: resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_execution_role" {
> ```

My terraform settings:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "nginx" {
  family = "nginx-${var.app}"

  network_mode             = "awsvpc"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]

  cpu    = "256"
  memory = "512"

  execution_role_arn = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.arn}"
  task_role_arn      = "${aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.arn}"

  container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
  [
 ...
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_execution_role" {
  name = "ecs_task_execution_role"
 
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
         "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
          "sts:AssumeRole",
          "ecs:CreateCluster",
          "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
          "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
          "ecs:Poll",
          "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
          "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
          "ecs:Submit*",
          "ecs:StartTask",
          "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
          "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
          "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
          "ecr:BatchGetImage",
          "logs:CreateLogStream",
          "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }    
  ]
}
EOF

}
```

What policy do I need? what is wrong with current policy?

When I change the action property in the policy to `"Action": "sts:AssumeRole"` I get this error in the task log:

```
Status reason   CannotPullECRContainerError: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::993934193145:assumed-role/ecs_task_execution_role/0d2f817c-d7b5-4221-afb8-56baaee68b0e is not authorized to perform: ecr:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: * status code: 400, request
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assume_role_policy` in [aws_iam_role](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role) is only for trust relationship, i.e. which IAM entity can assume the role.

The actually permissions you want to added to the role, could be placed in [aws_iam_policy](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_policy) and attached to the role using [aws_iam_role_policy_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_role_policy_attachment).

For example, your code could be refactored into the following:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_execution_role" {
  name = "ecs_task_execution_role"
 
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
         "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }    
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "ecs_permissions" {
  name        = "my_ecs_permissions"
  description = "Permissions to enable CT"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ecs:CreateCluster",
        "ecs:DeregisterContainerInstance",
        "ecs:DiscoverPollEndpoint",
        "ecs:Poll",
        "ecs:RegisterContainerInstance",
        "ecs:StartTelemetrySession",
        "ecs:Submit*",
        "ecs:StartTask",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "logs:CreateLogStream",
        "logs:PutLogEvents"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }    
  ]
}
EOF
}


resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_attachment" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_execution_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.ecs_permissions.arn
}
```

Comment: Seems working but I got another error. `Status reason CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)` maybe need to add more permission or this is another problem?

Comment: @JonSud Hi. Yes, this is new issue. Seems your tasks can't connect to the ECR service. Maybe they have no access to internet. You can make new question about it, with relevant details how are tasks setup to access internet, nat gateway or vpc endpoint for ecr and s3.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually down to the `assume_role_policy` containing both the trust policy and the permissions

Instead you should move all not trust policy permissions into a standard `policy`

> This assume_role_policy is very similar but slightly different than just a standard IAM policy and cannot use an aws_iam_policy resource. It can however, use an aws_iam_policy_document data source, see example below for how this could work.